# F11 key doesnot work on the ESXi server in the VMWARE

Tags: server, key, vmware, esxi

I tried installing the ESXi server on the VMware workstation. While trying to proceed after going through the license agreement, it is asking for validation to proceed to the installation of the ESXi. When I press F11 for validating that page, only the key works outside the VMware.(F11 key is defined for decreasing the brightness- even if I am inside the virtual machine and press the F11 key, it is just accessing the outside and not on the VMWare). Only enter and escape are the keys, I am able to access inside the Vmware. Have anyone faced a similar problem? or if someone knows the solution for it?

I tried with alt + F11 ( from google) but still, I am not able to validate that page as that key is not working in VMware.

Comment: This is more a  question for Server Fault https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Usually machines that have the `F*` keys redefined to actions like changing the brightness or volume, there is another key (on Macs it's `fn`) that has to pressed with the top row function key for it to register as a function keypress rather than trigger the action it's been assigned to.

Answer (score 3):

I was on an iMAC using a Windows PC keyboard, (not the iMAC's original keyboard), RDP'ed into a Windows10 machine, trying to build a lab using VMware Player and installing a nested ESXi.

I had trouble going past the F11 during the installation (acceptance of the terms and conditions page) of ESXi.

I tried everything, even rebooting the remote machine. Finally,  pressing the Windows Logo + F11 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f11</kbd> worked for me when i had a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hope this help someone, especially the Mac users. Default keyboard configuration is not Mac. Toggle it.